# Horizontally align asp.net menu on the top

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu, menu

```
 <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" ForeColor="Blue"
                    StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Style="font-size: medium; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 0px;
                    margin-bottom: 0px; color: #333333; text-align: left;" Width="180px" BorderStyle="None"
                    SkipLinkText="" Height="358px">
                    <StaticMenuStyle BorderStyle="None" />
                    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" BorderStyle="Solid"
                        BorderColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" />
                    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#5E2433" ForeColor="White" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle BorderColor="#666666" Width="130px" BackColor="#EFEDED" />
                    <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle Width="130px" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px"
                        HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#5E2433" ForeColor="White" />
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Register New Patient" Value="Register New Patient" NavigateUrl="DoctorNewRegisteration.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Wait List" Value="Wait List" NavigateUrl="DoctorWaitList.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Appointments" Value="Appointments" 
                            NavigateUrl="DoctorAppointments.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="DoctorCheckup.aspx" Text="Patient Visit" Value="Patient Visit">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Add/Delete Vaccine" Value="Add/Delete Vaccine" NavigateUrl="DoctorNewVaccine.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Vaccination Schedule" Value="Vaccination Schedule" NavigateUrl="DoctorVacSchedule.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Vaccination Due List" Value="Vaccination Due List" NavigateUrl="DoctorVacDueList.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="My Profile" Value="My Profile" NavigateUrl="DoctorMyProfile.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Announcements" Value="Announcements" NavigateUrl="DoctorAnnouncements.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Reference Documents" Value="Reference Documents" NavigateUrl="DoctorUploadDoc.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Message To Patients" Value="Message To Patients" NavigateUrl="DoctorMessage.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Inactive List" Value="Inactive List" 
                            NavigateUrl="DoctorInactiveList.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="DoctorBirthList.aspx" Text="Birthday List" 
                            Value="Birthday List"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Change Password" Value="Change Password" NavigateUrl="DoctorChangePassword.aspx">
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="DoctorMenuPage.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Logout" Value="Logout"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
```

How do i align this asp.net menu horizontally on the top right now it is vertically aligned on the left side.

Please help should i use css or change some properties of the Asp.net menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the menu control has a setting `orientation="Horizontal"` or you can add it to the attributes manually

--EDIT
when you change the orientation to horizontal you have to make sure that the menu would fit the given width in that orientation. you have set the width to 180px, if you remove that the menu orients itself horizontally automatically

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" ForeColor="Blue"
                    StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" Style="font-size: medium; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 0px;
                    margin-bottom: 0px; color: #333333; text-align: left;"  BorderStyle="None"
                    SkipLinkText="" Height="358px" orientation="Horizontal">
```

Comment: Its not working when i do that would css be better in this scenario?

Comment: no you should use the menu's original settings, it's much easier. it works for me, you should try again without any css and just the menu with default setting and only a horizontal orientation

Comment: see the edit I've made regarding the width of the menu. that might be why you are having problems